# EF - class split into different tables

Tags: entity-framework

I have an existing software that has tree tables for a single class.

`users`, `users_a` and `users_b` with the same primary key `user_id`.

How can I model such kind of tables with Entity Framework and C# - Code First, so I have one class `User` and all the properties from the three tables are assigned to this class?

```
table: users

users_id int
name nvarchar
....

table: users_a

users_id int
race_id int
......

table: users_b

users_id int
genders_id int
...
```

I need a class User

```
User

public int Id { get;set;}
public int GenderId {get;set;}
public virtual Gender Gender {get;set;}
public int RaceId {get;set;}
public virtual Race Race {get;set;}
```

Comment: Look for *entity splitting*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the class by overriding the "OnModelCreating" method of the DbContext Class.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .Map(map =>
        {
            map.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.UserId,
                p.Name
            });
            map.ToTable("users");
        })
        .Map(map =>
        {
            map.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.UserId,
                p.GenderId
            });
            map.ToTable("users_b");
        })
        .Map(map =>
        {
            map.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.UserId,
                p.RaceId
            });
            map.ToTable("users_a");
        });           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This structure can be implemented by using Table per Hierarchy. For details see [Asp.net example](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: I have 1 user type with properties in the tree tables. I do not have different types of users.